# tensor calculus for undergraduates ? (textbooks)

Tags: reference-request, tensors

What textbook would you suggest for undergraduates to learn about tensors?  I am looking for an introductory book about tensors and tensor calculus.

Thanks!

Comment: A lot depends on whether you're looking for a treatment for mathematics students or for engineering/physics students, and thus it would help if you said more about your background and about your reasons for learning the material. If you're looking for something relevant to engineering/physics, then one or more of the books briefly discussed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3048563/13130) might be useful to you.

Comment: My question refers more for mathematics student as me.

Comment: For a mathematics, then maybe [**A Brief on Tensor Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/038794088X) by Simmonds or [**Tensor Geometry**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/354052018X) by Dodson/Poston. Both are supposedly directed toward engineering/physics students, but both are also written from a fairly mathematical viewpoint. At a more advanced level, there's a lot about tensors (and explaining the difference between math and physics notations for them) in [**A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0914098705) by Spivak.

Comment: dig into the ad hoc tags here in MSE, there are a lot of them related to

Comment: [Tensor analysis on manifolds](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486640396.html) by Bishop and Goldberg is inexpensive (Dover) and quite modern despite the publication date and modest prerequisites.

Comment: I've always liked [The Geometry of Physics](https://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Physics-Introduction-Theodore-Frankel/dp/1107602602/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=geometry+of+physics+frankel&qid=1621063993&s=books&sr=1-3) by Frankel.

Comment: I think it's worth looking at [A Student's Guide to Vectors and Tensors](https://www.amazon.com/Students-Guide-Vectors-Tensors-Guides/dp/0521171903).

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering and recommending me those books, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of good references discussing the topic in different ways. Let me list some of my favourites:

1. [The Geometry of Physics - T. Frankel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107602602)
2. [Geometry, Topology and Physics - M. Nakahara](https://www.amazon.com.br/Geometry-Topology-Physics-Second-Nakahara/dp/0750306068/ref=asc_df_0750306068/?tag=googleshopp00-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=379787555408&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=2204042857230534473&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1001773&hvtargid=pla-457907756132&psc=1)
3. [Analysis on Manifolds - J. Munkres](https://www.amazon.com.br/Analysis-Manifolds-James-R-Munkres/dp/0201315963)
4. [Multilinear Algebra - W. Greub](https://www.amazon.com.br/Multilinear-Algebra-Werner-Hildbert-Greub/dp/0387902848)
5. [Linear Algebra via Exterior Products - S. Winitzki](https://www.amazon.com.br/Linear-Algebra-Via-Exterior-Products/dp/140929496X)
6. [Advanced Linear Algebra - S. Roman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387728287)

The first two books treat a large amount of subjects in mathematics, including tensor calculus, geometry etc. The aim is to provide a bridge between mathematics and physics. In Munkres's book, you will find a nice exposition about tensor products of vector spaces, which is used in the study of multivariate integrals. Greub's book is a more abstract account on the subject (and, in my opinion, more advanced), but a very nice reference too. Maybe Winitzki's book is more appropriate for you, since the book is a linear algebra-type of book, so it has proofs for theorems and some nice tools for direct applications too. Roman's book also treats the case of tensor products of vector spaces.