# Appropriate books for tensors

Tags: tensors, book-recommendation

I have studied Calc 3 and the basics of Vector Calculus using Stewart's text *Calculus: Early Transcendentals*. I have also studied *Vector Calculus* by Marsden and Tromba, but didn't pay much attention on differential forms. Currently, I am studying *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Serge Lang.

I am looking for a book on tensor analysis and tensor calculus. My main focus right now is the mathematical aspect and the applications of tensors in physics. *A Student's Guide to Vectors and Tensors* by Fleisch felt quite good as an explanatory book, but IMO, it was mathematically lacking. I don't wanna focus more on differential geometry right now. Though many books do add some topics and I don't mind that.

What do you recommend as a good book for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some suggestions, see the comments and answers to [tensor calculus for undergraduates ? (textbooks)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4138755/13130) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3048563/13130).

Comment: You can check the last chapter of Tristan Needham's Visual Differential Geometry for an easy intuitive explanation of tensors. The rest of the book is for Geometric intuition building. I also like the book Tensor Calculus by Pavel Grinfeld for teaching only the tensor algebra.